# Authenticating by twitter in Nodejs stateless

Tags: node.js, twitter, passport.js, stateless, passport-twitter

I am developing stateless APIs and authenticating using JWT and passport, but currently, I want to add "login with Twitter" and maybe discord too.
The problem is they all use sessions for authentication, while I do not have sessions in my app.

I was thinking about redirecting the user to login at Twitter and save his "TwitterId" in my DB, then each time I would just check the returned "TwitterId" if it's okay I can sign a JWT token and return it to the user so he can use it in calling the other APIs, same as I do in regular logins.

I am having a lot of problems doing that as I do not know much about sessions and I have tried some packages like [passport-twitter](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-twitter/) and [login-with-twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/login-with-twitter) but I can not make them work the way I want.

If anyone has done that before please provide some guidance.